# When creating a DSL in Ruby, is it possible to create an alternate version of `def`?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dsl

It is possible to call `define_method` directly or from within a method call that accepts a block. But is it possible to create a new method or keyword that performs manipulation on code and then declares it into a method, but has the same syntax as the built-in `def`?

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulation on code"?

Comment: I personally can not parse the question to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can define a method, but you cannot define a keyword. Whatever method you define on the `Module` class, you cannot pass a method body to it without the `do` keyword, unlike with `def`.